# Symfony routing, separate route setup and ignore _locale prefix?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-routing

I have in my annotations.yaml following setup to use annotation route setup:

```
controllers:
    resource: '../../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        en: ''
        sr: '/es'
        de: '/fr'
kernel:
    resource: ../../src/Kernel.php
    type: annotation
```

My question here is can I create a separated area like `mysite.com/userarea` without locale prefix?

It's protected area and I can use users language. I tried with this [symfony route docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-in-yaml-xml-or-php-files) but I would like to keep annotations.

At the moment it looks like `mysite.com/es/userarea` but I would wish `mysite.com/userarea`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create a dedicated namespace on controllers and create another annotation configuration like this :

```yaml
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/*
    exclude: ../../src/Controller/Admin
    type: annotation

secure_area:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/Admin/*
    prefix: /userarea
    type: annotation
```

Comment: Hi, this seemed to be the solution to my problem, but this not working as expected. It seems when we specify resource with *, the subdirectories are ignored (and I need the subdirectories too :/ ). Do you have a workaround ?

Comment: Hi, removing the '*' should work, I think

Comment: I checked Symfony internal code, and there is a condition than resources must contains *, [ or {

Comment: What is your Symfony version ?